# Conexión a bd desde C# - No permite usar el SqlConection

Tags: c#, sql-server

Cordial saludo, feliz madrugada

Tengo una duda, ya lo había hecho antes pero no con este pc y es la conexión a la bd de SqlServer.
El problema que tengo  es que no me permite  usar la referencia: using System.Data.SqlClient;
Debería sugerir usar la cadena, que se ponga en verde, pero no me permite, quedaría muy agradecida si me pueden ayudar, gracias.
[! [image: ][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HjQd.png)

Comment: No has declarado el tipo de la variable. Por otro lado, mira [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien acogidas. Copia el código e intenta evitar poner imágenes siempre que puedas.

Comment: En C# las variables se declaran con su nivel de acceso, su tipo y su nombre. Te falta el tipo, como dice Miguel.

`private SqlConnection sqlConnection;`

Comment: Si, yo entiendo esa parte y les agradezco mucho, pero después de hacerlo el problema persiste, por ello les mostré el pantallazo :c Aunque sé que lo mostré incompleto.

Answer (score 0):

A simple vista me parece que tienes diferentes errores en tu estructura.

1. Tienes una clase privada CapaDatos y dentro de ella una clase Publica del mismo nombre
2. Si no te toma el namespace de System.Data.SqlClient probablemente no tienes la dependencia instalada, al ser un programa de consola esas utilidades no vienen pre-instaladas, revisa eso.

[image: Imaden de Packages en .NET]

[image: NugetPackages]